# Row's children must not contain any null values, but a null value was found at index 0

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I'm developing a Flutter license plate scan application, when running the application there is an error "Row's children must not contain any null values, but a null value was found at index 0". Here is the source code that I uploaded on github.

https://github.com/AdityaWiradarma/Aplikasi-Scan-Plat-Kendaraan.git

Comment: Please share minimum reproducible code in the question because we cannot spend too much time reading all your code in Github.

Comment: share minimum code not the github link

Answer (score 1):

Use `ElevatedButton` instead of `RaisedButton`. `RaisedButton` was deprecated and remove from Flutter so no more exist.

```dart
                Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ElevatedButton(//RaisedButton got replaced
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          klik = true;
                          pickImageCamera();
                        });
                      },
                      child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          klik = true;
                          pickImageGallery();
                        });
                      },
                      child: Icon(Icons.photo),
                    ),
                    // RaisedButton(
                    //   onPressed: readText,
                    //   child: Text("Baca"),
                    // ),
                  ],
                )
```

I hope this helps